# Directional derivative and the gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I couldn't find the solution of this question, can you help me, please?

Let the function f(x,y,z) be differentiable at a point P. The maximum value of the directional derivative of f at P is 6 and the direction of v=(1,1,-1). Find the the gradient vector of f at P.

Comment: Do you know the relation between the directional derivative and the gradient?

Comment: Yes, I know the relation between them.

Comment: Knowing that and the bound $-\| x \| \| y \|  \leq x \cdot y \leq \| x \| \| y \|$ (called the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality), you can finish the problem.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for that

Answer (score 3):

The gradient is the vector pointed in the direction of maximum ascent, and its size is the rate at which the function is ascending.  With that definition, you can see that we have all the information we need.

We have the direction of maximum ascent:  $$(1,1,-1).$$
A unit vector in that direction is $$(1,1,-1)/\sqrt{3}.$$  And we know the rate of ascent is $6$; therefore, the gradient is $$\left(6/\sqrt{3}\right)(1,1,-1).$$

Comment: Give a man a fish, ....

Comment: Is that it? When the question says the gradient vector I thought it would be different. I got confused by the word vector.

Comment: @irchans Please concern yourself with own methods of instruction.  I will concern myself with mine.

Comment: @KaanIzmir What about the word confused you, do you think?

Comment: It was on my final exam so I thought the solution was complicated , I tried to find a vector that depends on x,y,z

Comment: @NicNic8   Sorry.    For what it's worth, I found your explanation to be very clear.

Comment: And I found your solution very clear, thanks for the answer, it helped a lot